# Драйверы Nvidia не работают

Tags: nvidia

При установке любого ядра, кроме стандартного, драйверы не работают, я также установил его через Центр приложений

EOS 6
Gtx 850m
ASUS g550

Comment: I've always used the xanmod kernel and everything worked. now does not work. put both 5.10 and 5.14. nbidia 470.74 from app center - not working

Comment: There isn’t enough information here to offer anything concrete. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Elementary you’re running (1) the brand/model of the computer (2) the model of the nvidia card (3) the exact commands you used to install the driver. With this, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: edited
thank you for the answer